# showModalDialog HeIp

Tags: javascript

How can I use the return value assigned to a call to `showModalDialog`, i,e,

```
var fn = window.showModalDialog(...)`
```

I have two buttons on my modal dialog and when I press "No", can this be captured somehow against `fn` as I need to clear my parent form that called the `showModalDialog`?

Furthermore, is it possible to call a Javascript function within my parent form from the `showModalDialog` window, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onclick of button set the value you want to return

```
window.returnValue = 'your value'

var fn = window.showModaiDialog(...)  // fn will capture the data

alert(fn) ;// will show your value
```